# Añadir colores al Administrador de tintas de PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

En Acrobat PRO, cuando se abre un PDF es posible ver el administrador de tintas y sus colores, como estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un código en PHP con las librerías **TCPDF** y **Imagemagick** para crear un PDF con dos capas, y en cada una de ellas una imagen. Pero necesito añadir otro color a este administrador de tintas, ¿es posible hacerlo? No encuentro mucho sobre ello.

Así creo el PDF:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm');

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage('L', array(60.4, 11.3));
```

Y justo después, añado las capas y las imágenes. ¿Hay alguna función que permita hacer lo que necesito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

En el caso de querer añadir nuevos colores para que el administrador de tintas de Adobe PRO lo reconozca hay que añadir lo siguiente:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', 'mm');

// Añadir color
$pdf->addSpotColor('RDG_WHITE', 25, 25, 25, 25);
```

Para ver un ejemplo completo, os dejo la [documentación](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_037/). Ahí os explica con detalle cuales son los parámetros, y que tipo de objeto devuelve.